# MySQL Order By and Group By issue

Tags: mysql, group-by

I have two fields in a MySQL table:

```
q31
q31_theme
```

`q31` contains comments and `q31_theme` the theme, so the data looks like the following:

```
q31               q31_theme
Sunny and hot     Good weather
Cold and wet      Bad weather
Sunshine          Good weather
Bright and sunny  Good weather
No comment        N/A
Foggy             Bad weather
Raining           Bad weather
Cloudy and cold   Bad weather
```

What I would like to do is bring back the data using a query that shows the data in the following: the comments in q31 back in alphabetical order but ordered by q31_theme where the theme count is in descending order, so it would look like this:

```
q31               q31_theme         Count
Cloudy and cold   Bad weather       4
Cold and wet      Bad weather       4
Foggy             Bad weather       4
Raining           Bad weather       4
Bright and sunny  Good weather      3
Sunny and hot     Good weather      3
Sunshine          Good weather      3
No comment        N/A               1
```

The `count` column is the number of comments in the theme.

I have tried the following, which brings back

```
SELECT q31, q31_theme, COUNT( q31_theme ) AS Count
FROM  `results` 
GROUP BY q31_theme
ORDER BY Count DESC
```

Bu this only brings back one comment for each theme, clearly a Grouping issue (I think) but I can't work out how to achieve my desired outcome (assuming it is possible).

Any and all advice welcomed.

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you've not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you've not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Comment: @Strawberry - appreciate the feedback - the desired result set it setout in the question above.  Is that not enough?

Comment: @Strawberry - I notice you didn't offer this user the same advise...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20269637/mysql-complex-self-join/20270192#20270192

Comment: Times change. People change. What's your point?

Comment: That, sadly, SO is becoming less tolerant.  Which is a shame.

Comment: I don't follow. I made a suggestion. You didn't follow it. Fine. So what?

Comment: If you like, consider the way in which you replied to my question.  I was polite, acknowledged your feedback, pointed out that the desired result was already set-out, clearly, in the question.

Comment: Sorry. You've lost me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select r.*, t.count
from results r
join
(
  SELECT q31_theme, COUNT(*) AS Count
  FROM results 
  where q31_theme is not null and q31_theme <> ''
  GROUP BY q31_theme
) t on t.q31_theme = r.q31_theme
ORDER BY t.Count DESC,
         r.q31 ASC
```

Comment: Thanks juergen d - implement but get the following, just trying to work out why: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '.count from results r join ( SELECT q31_theme, COUNT(*) AS C' at line 1

Comment: I forgot a comma in the first line. Try again now.

Comment: That looks pretty good to me.  As an aside, how would I go about excluding blanks/nulls/empties in q31_theme?

Comment: add a `where` clause to the inner select: `where q31_theme is not null and q31_theme <> ''`